# How do I correct . . . 'Settings' is ambiguous between declarations in Modules ... .My.CopyOfMySettingsProperty'

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Good Day All,

I’m new to programming. I’m using Visual Studio 2010. I’m taking into two introduction classes, VB and C# with .Net.  I have seen the enemy and he is me.  I hope that someone can please help me with my two errors.

I do not know how I created My.CopyOfMySettingsProperty but I do know they were created when I was trying to create a project by combining my previous four projects.

Listed are the two errors from my error list window that I need to correct along with my offending code:

```
Error   1   'Settings' is ambiguous between declarations in Modules 'Assign5Multi.My.MySettingsProperty' and 'Assign5Multi.My.CopyOfMySettingsProperty'.    F:\ProjectsVBA\VBAssignment4Movies\My Project\Settings.Designer.vb  34  13  prjAssign5Multi

Error   2   'Settings' is ambiguous between declarations in Modules 'Assign5Multi.My.MySettingsProperty' and 'Assign5Multi.My.CopyOfMySettingsProperty'.    F:\ProjectsVBA\VBAssignment4Movies\My Project\Settings.Designer.vb      76  17  prjAssign5Multi
```

These are my Google Searchs before this  StackOverflow post, “"Visual Studio 2010" and "CopyOfMySettingsProperty"” and “"Visual Basic" and "CopyOfMySettingsProperty"” received zero results.

From Settings.Designer.vb . . .

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.239
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


Namespace My

    <Global.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0"),  _
     Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)>  _
    Partial Friend NotInheritable Class MySettings
        Inherits Global.System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase

        Private Shared defaultInstance As MySettings = CType(Global.System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(New MySettings()),MySettings)

#Region "My.Settings Auto-Save Functionality"
#If _MyType = "WindowsForms" Then
    Private Shared addedHandler As Boolean

    Private Shared addedHandlerLockObject As New Object

    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)> _
    Private Shared Sub AutoSaveSettings(ByVal sender As Global.System.Object, ByVal e As Global.System.EventArgs)
        If My.Application.SaveMySettingsOnExit Then
            My.Settings.Save()
        End If
    End Sub
#End If
#End Region

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property [Default]() As MySettings
            Get

#If _MyType = "WindowsForms" Then
               If Not addedHandler Then
                    SyncLock addedHandlerLockObject
                        If Not addedHandler Then
                            AddHandler My.Application.Shutdown, AddressOf AutoSaveSettings
                            addedHandler = True
                        End If
                    End SyncLock
                End If
#End If
                Return defaultInstance
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class


    <Global.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute(), _
        Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0"), _
        Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)> _
    Partial Friend NotInheritable Class CopyOfMySettings
        Inherits Global.System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase

        Private Shared defaultInstance As CopyOfMySettings = CType(Global.System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(New CopyOfMySettings()), CopyOfMySettings)

#Region "My.Settings Auto-Save Functionality"
#If _MyType = "WindowsForms" Then
        Private Shared addedHandler As Boolean

        Private Shared addedHandlerLockObject As New Object

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)> _
        Private Shared Sub AutoSaveSettings(ByVal sender As Global.System.Object, ByVal e As Global.System.EventArgs)
            If My.Application.SaveMySettingsOnExit Then
                My.Settings.Save()
            End If
        End Sub
#End If
#End Region

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property [Default]() As CopyOfMySettings
            Get

#If _MyType = "WindowsForms" Then
                If Not addedHandler Then
                    SyncLock addedHandlerLockObject
                        If Not addedHandler Then
                            AddHandler My.Application.Shutdown, AddressOf AutoSaveSettings
                            addedHandler = True
                        End If
                    End SyncLock
                End If
#End If
                Return defaultInstance
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace

Namespace My

    <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.HideModuleNameAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()>  _
    Friend Module MySettingsProperty

        <Global.System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("My.Settings")>  _
        Friend ReadOnly Property Settings() As Global.Assign5Multi.My.MySettings
            Get
                Return Global.Assign5Multi.My.MySettings.Default
            End Get
        End Property
    End Module


    <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.HideModuleNameAttribute(), _
        Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
        Global.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()> _
    Friend Module CopyOfMySettingsProperty

        <Global.System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("My.Settings")> _
        Friend ReadOnly Property Settings() As Global.Assign5Multi.My.MySettings
            Get
                Return Global.Assign5Multi.My.MySettings.Default
            End Get
        End Property
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the class that starts with:

```
<Global.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute(), _
    Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0"), _
    Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)> _
Partial Friend NotInheritable Class CopyOfMySettings
```

and the reference to it:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.HideModuleNameAttribute(), _
    Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
    Global.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()> _
Friend Module CopyOfMySettingsProperty

    <Global.System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("My.Settings")> _
    Friend ReadOnly Property Settings() As Global.Assign5Multi.My.MySettings
        Get
            Return Global.Assign5Multi.My.MySettings.Default
        End Get
    End Property
End Module
```

Comment: I commented out the class and the reference to it (at least I think I did :)  and the errors went away -Thank You Very Much competent_tech

Comment: That's excellent. So that others are aware that this resolved your problem, can you click on the checkbox next to the answer and the up arrow? Thanks!

Comment: you now have answered a second question for me again Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got a simple solution
simply delete `Settings.settings` and `Settings.designer.vb` files from `My Project` folder and reload your project it will automatically load settings from the `Application.config` File

That Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Just go to solution explore and from references remove system dll. Then the application will be successfully run.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had two Settings.Settings files (one was actually settings.settings1 because of some cut and paste error or something)

Deleted one of them and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the class did not work for me. I did remove the files and that made the situation worse.

My fix was to build a new project in a different folder and readd the settings and then add all the other files from the projec. Worked fine.